# Javascript merge array multidimensional?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mergesort

Thank you very much for your answers. Your answers are correct according to the question. The question was incomplete due to my mistake. When combining user names, the amount paid field must be collected. I am reorganizing the code.

```
const array =[
{
  name: 'Iphone',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/iphone.png',
  cost: 2500,
  paid: 500,
  username:"Joe",
},
{
  name: 'Samsung',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/samsung.png',
  cost: 2000,
  paid: 200,
  username:"Adam",
},
{
  name: 'Samsung',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/samsung.png',
  cost: 2000,
  paid: 100,
  username:"Alvin",
}
]
```

This is the data coming from my database. With the new arrangement, I want to combine them as follows. I need to sum the values in the Paid field.

```
const array =[
{
 name: 'Iphone',
 date: '01.01.2024',
 img: 'img/iphone.png',
 cost: 2500,
 paid: 500,
 username:"Joe",
},
{
 name: 'Samsung',
 date: '01.01.2024',
 img: 'img/samsung.png',
 cost: 2000,
 paid: 300,   <---  paid sum from 2 samsung array
 usernames:[
   {username : "Adam"},
   {username : "Alvin"}
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Please update the question to include a text-based [mcve]. Include input, current output, and desired output.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so we may help you fix it - this is not a "coding" for free site but a "help you fix your code with a stated challenge" site.

Comment: what the grouping property/properties?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Iphone',
        date: '01.01.2024',
        img: 'img/iphone.png',
        cost: 2500,
        username: 'Joe',
    },
    {
        name: 'Samsung',
        date: '01.01.2024',
        img: 'img/samsung.png',
        cost: 2000,
        username: 'Adam',
    },
    {
        name: 'Samsung',
        date: '01.01.2024',
        img: 'img/samsung.png',
        cost: 2000,
        username: 'Alvin',
    },
];

const processedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const found = acc.find(
        (user) =>
            user.name === curr.name &&
            user.date === curr.date &&
            user.img === curr.img &&
            user.cost === curr.cost
    );

    if (found) {
        found.usernames.push({ username: curr.username });
    } else {
        acc.push({
            name: curr.name,
            date: curr.date,
            img: curr.img,
            cost: curr.cost,
            usernames: [{ username: curr.username }],
        });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);
```

This code uses the reduce function to iterate through the initial array and create a new array (resultArray) in the desired format by checking if an object with the same 'name', 'date', 'img', and 'cost' already exists in the accumulator (acc). If it exists, it pushes the 'username' to the 'usernames' array. Otherwise, it creates a new object and initializes the 'usernames' array with the current 'username'.

Comment: perhaps make a runnable snippet from the sample code to better allow evaluation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the unique phone names.

Then, for each name, find the matching phone entry, and extract all properties in to a new object. Then, add in all usernames for that phone name.

Finally, if there is more than one username, delete the username property for each object in the resulting array, so that there is only a usernames property at the top level. Otherwise, keep only the username property and delete the usernames property.

```js
const array = [{"name":"Iphone","date":"01.01.2024","img":"img/iphone.png","cost":2500,"username":"Joe"},{"name":"Samsung","date":"01.01.2024","img":"img/samsung.png","cost":2000,"username":"Adam"},{"name":"Samsung","date":"01.01.2024","img":"img/samsung.png","cost":2000,"username":"Alvin"}]

let names = [...new Set(array.map(i=>i.name))]

let array2 = names.map(name => ({
  ...array.find(i => i.name===name),
  usernames: array.filter(i => i.name===name)
                  .map(({username}) => ({username}))
}))

array2.forEach(i => {
  if(i.usernames.length > 1) delete i.username
  else delete i.usernames
})

console.log(array2)
```

Comment: This has both `"username": "Adam",` and the array of users - which is not what the OP posted.

Comment: i.e. singular when one, array when multiple

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss oops, thanks, there was a bug. fixed now

Comment: Cool, odd spec which I suspect is actually "wrong" but the OP tried nothing but the before/after at this point either.

Comment: it's not definite that only phone name should be used. there could different phones with the same name (different dates, prices)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a simple array for the usernames. That accepted, a possible solution could look like this:

```js
const arr =[
{
  name: 'Iphone',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/iphone.png',
  cost: 2500,
  paid: 500,
  username:"Joe",
},
{
  name: 'Samsung',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/samsung.png',
  cost: 2000,
  paid: 200,
  username:"Adam",
},
{
  name: 'Samsung',
  date: '01.01.2024',
  img: 'img/samsung.png',
  cost: 2000,
  paid: 100,
  username:"Alvin",
}];

const res=Object.values(arr.reduce((a,c)=>{
 const k=c.name+c.date+c.img+c.cost;
 if (!a[k]){ a[k]={...c, usernames:[]}; delete a[k].username;}
 else a[k].paid+=c.paid; 
 a[k].usernames.push(c.username);
 return a;
},{}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The OP has `username:"Joe",` rather than the array when only a singular exists.  Odd but that is the OP spec.

Comment: Yes, as stated in my answer, I am aware that my result looks slightly different from what OP requested. I merely suggested this simpler format as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, build a tree of property values with the leaves being object unique by all fields except `username`. The code supports any number of properties and can be put in a function with the array property name as a parameter.

```js
const result = array.reduce(((cached, keys, lastKey) => (r, item) => {
  if(!keys){
    keys = Object.keys(item).filter(key => key !== 'username');
    lastKey = keys.pop();
  }
  let node = cached;
  for(const key of keys){
    node = node[item[key]] ??= {};
  }
  const found = node[item[lastKey]];
  if(!found){
     r[r.length] = node[item[lastKey]] = {...item};
  }else{
    if(found.usernames){
      found.usernames.push({username: item.username});
    }else{
      found.usernames = [{username: found.username}, {username: item.username}];
      delete found.username;
    }
  }
  return r;
})({}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const array=[{name:"Iphone",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/iphone.png",cost:2500,username:"Joe"},{name:"Samsung",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/samsung.png",cost:2e3,username:"Adam"},{name:"Samsung",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/samsung.png",cost:2e3,username:"Alvin"}];
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/120
-------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x1000000  660  680  683  719  745
Carsten     1.19x  |  x1000000  783  828  836  842  846
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
// @benchmark Carsten     

Object.values(array.reduce((a,c)=>{
 const k=c.name+c.date+c.img+c.cost;
 if (!a[k]){ a[k]={...c, usernames:[]}; delete a[k].username;}
 a[k].usernames.push(c.username);
 return a;
},{}));


// @benchmark Alexander

array.reduce(((cached, keys, lastKey) => (r, item) => {
  if(!keys){
    keys = Object.keys(item).filter(key => key !== 'username');
    lastKey = keys.pop();
  }
  let node = cached;
  for(const key of keys){
    node = node[item[key]] ??= {};
  }
  const found = node[item[lastKey]];
  if(!found){
     r[r.length] = node[item[lastKey]] = {...item};
  }else{
    if(found.usernames){
      found.usernames.push({username: item.username});
    }else{
      found.usernames = [{username: found.username}, {username: item.username}];
      delete found.username;
    }
  }
  return r;
})({}), []);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

```html
<script>
const array=[{name:"Iphone",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/iphone.png",cost:2500,username:"Joe"},{name:"Samsung",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/samsung.png",cost:2e3,username:"Adam"},{name:"Samsung",date:"01.01.2024",img:"img/samsung.png",cost:2e3,username:"Alvin"}];
</script>
```

Comment: The OP has `username:"Joe",` rather than the array when only a singular exists. Odd but that is the OP spec. i.e. your second example

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss my code follows the spec, i've added Carsten's answer for speed comparison, though it doesnt follow, i guess when fixed it will be slower

Comment: Yes, probably given the odd spec speed optimization is not a worry compared to functional/results.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss just extra 3 lines plus it's dynamic, any number of properties supported